# react-redux useCallback infinite render

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to pass a "action dispatch" to a child component and am stuck in an infinite render loop, here is a simple example of what I have:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const error = useSelector(getError);
  const fetching = useSelector(getFetching);
  const things = useSelector(getThings);

  const fetchData = useCallback(arg => { dispatch(fetchThings(arg)); });
  return (
   {error && <span>{error}</span>}
   {fetching &&< <span>Fetching...</span>}
   {!fetching && (
     <ChildComponent fetchData={fetchData} data={things} />
   })
  );
};

const ChildComponent = ({fetchData, data, ...otherStuff}) => {
  const [arg, setArg] = useState();
  useEffect(() => { fetchData(arg); }, [fetchData, arg]);

  return (
   ... MARKUP ...
  );
};
export default ChildComponent;
```

"arg" is a variable in the child I can change in the UI and I want the data refectched when it changes. On initial render (and infinite render) I can see that it never changes.
[Per the docs](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#examples), it looks Ok to me; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you place an empty dependency array in useEffect, do you still get the infinite loop? Not suggesting this as a fix, just a troubleshooting step.  If that stops the loop, it tells you where your issue is at.

Comment: It still happened. I see when I dispatch the fetch, that changes the fetching variable state, which re-renders the parent, which kicks everything back off. Not sure how to handle, this was just converting a Container/Presenter redux connnect pattern to hooks.

Comment: I think the issue is that `useCallback` also needs a dependency array or it will create a new callback on every render which is changing `fetchData` and causing `useEffect` to run again. You'll see that `dispatch` is passed to the callback dependency array in the example you linked from the docs. So should be `const fetchData = useCallback(arg => { dispatch(fetchThings(arg)); }, [dispatch]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here, as @azundo pointed in the comments, is the lack of dependencies in `useCallback`.

If no dependencies are passed, `useCallback` creates a new reference of the function in every render. When the function is passed to `ChildComponent` it is in fact a new function reference. So every render `useEffect(() => { fetchData(arg); }, [fetchData, arg]);` receives a new `fetchData` function and runs it.

To solve it simply pass dependencies to `useCallback`. In this case if the function inside `useCallback` won't change after the first render (I'm assuming neither `fetchThings` or `dispatch` change, if they do, pass them) we could pass an empty array.

```
const fetchData = useCallback(arg => { dispatch(fetchThings(arg)); }, []);
```

---

That said, if `ChildComponent` is not being memoized I'm not sure you are getting the benefits of `useCallback` as anyway it will render every time the parent does.

Comment: This is true but I actually had a dependency list in my args, I just missed that in my post. Additionally, the inline conditional rendering ({!fetching && <Child>) was removing and recreating the child (which fetched on every create) and causing the loop.